# Loop through all values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through a column and modify the adjacent column if a certain value is found.

I have it semi-working. It only modifies one value rather than all instances.

```
Sub PopulateField()

    For i = 2 To Rows.Count

        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "25 December 2018" Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = "Holiday"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

I would like it to be:

```
25 December 2018    Holiday
25 December 2018    Holiday
25 December 2018    Holiday
25 December 2018    Holiday
25 December 2018    Holiday
```

But currently it's only:

```
25 December 2018    Holiday
25 December 2018    
25 December 2018    
25 December 2018    
25 December 2018
```

It doesn't seem to be iterating over all values.

Comment: Also you probably don't need to loop to `Rows.Count`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) for how to find the last row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're exiting the loop after the first instance of `25 December 2018`.

Get rid of the `Exit For` to continue iterating.